# Which of the player's actions trigger a replay in Worms Armageddon?

Tags: worms-armageddon

In Worms Armageddon some of the player's actions may trigger an instant replay of what had happened a moment earlier. What is the exact algorithm that decides when to show a relpay?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If I'm reading the source code right:

- A Worm skimming across the surface of the water
- Using the Kamikaze weapon
- Pressing the <kbd>R</kbd> key
- 3 or more Worms dying in one turn
- 350 or more damage being dealt in one turn
- Game is over (one of the teams won)

Comment: What part of the source code shows the replay triggers?

Comment: @Stevoisiak I don't know how to answer that in a way which would be interesting or useful if you don't have the source code, or perhaps I misunderstood your question, please clarify.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev Oh, you’re the maintainer for Worms Armageddon! I was wondering where you found the source code. You may want to mention you’re a dev in the answer